# export Apple ProRes 422 HQ BT2020 PQ

Tags: ffmpeg

I have never used FFMPEG but I had an emergancy at work.

I need to convert an AVID DNXHR HQ PQ BT2020 in a Apple ProRes 422 HQ PQ BT2020.

I use Windows 10, and usually to make Apple Pro res I use the Adobe Media Encoder for the REC709.

This time I need BT2020 and Media Encoder change and destroy the color correction in the export.

I found this command string

```
ffmpeg -i inputVideo.mp4 \
-c:v prores_ks \
-profile:v 3 \
-vendor apl0 \
-bits_per_mb 8000 \
-pix_fmt yuv422p10le \
proRes422_output.mov
```

But I cannot find how to change the color profile from REC709 to BT2020 PQ.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This might be worth asking in https://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Show the **complete**
 log from your command.